# How do I prevent an empty state from rendering in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

So on an initial render I notice that there's a little flicker because there's a first rendering with the empty state of the user, but then there's a second rendering with the populated fetch data. How do I prevent that? And only have the fetch data in the first render from the beginning? Long story short how can I prevent the empty state from rendering and only have populated data in the initial render?

```
function App() {

 const [user, setUser] = useState({
   name:'',
   username:'',
   email:'',
 }); 

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`).then(res=>res.json()).then(json=>{
        setUser(json);
    });

 }, []);

return (
    <div className="App" style={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', flexDirection:'column', padding:'100px'}}>
   <div>
    <p>name:{user.name}</p> {/* these flicker blank for a split second before the fetch data is set */}
    <p>username:{user.username}</p>
    <p>email:{user.email}</p>
   </div>
  </div>
);
```

}

export default App;

Answer (score 3):

Set a loader

```
function App() {

const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [user, setUser] = useState({
   name:'',
   username:'',
   email:'',
 }); 

useEffect(() => {

    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1`).then(res=>res.json()).then(json=>{
        setUser(json);
        setIsLoading(false);
    });

 }, []);

if(isLoading){ return (<div> Loading ... </div>)}

return (
    <div className="App" style={{display:'flex', alignItems:'center', flexDirection:'column', padding:'100px'}}>
   <div>
    <p>name:{user.name}</p> {/* these flicker blank for a split second before the fetch data is set */}
    <p>username:{user.username}</p>
    <p>email:{user.email}</p>
   </div>
  </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Ah okay, that's what I did. Thank you.